# Why is Google maps latitude vertical and not horizontal?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, gis

I don't know why wiki show that latitude is horizontal and latitude is vertical on the Earth. But when using Google Map I see that latitude is vertical (-90, 90) and longtitude horizontal (-180, 180)

Can anyone show me that why?

Comment: Please provide the URL that you are referencing that is providing the erroneous information. [wikipedia Latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) [wikipedia Longitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude)

Comment: http://www.learner.org/jnorth/tm/LongitudeIntro.html it is the same. Sorry for my bad English understanding (I see the latitude image and it is horizontal)

Comment: Wouter is right - Greenwich is 0 degree longitude, Quito, on the equator is 0 degree latitude.
North pole is 90 degree North latitude South Pole is -90 degree South latitude.
Prime meridian runs north to south 0 degree longitude, the anti meridian runs north to south 180 degree longitude.
In other words, Latitude runs east to west, the equator. Longitude runs North to South, pole to pole

Comment: I suspect you're misinterpreting the order of coordinates as _(horizontal,vertical)_. This may be true for Cartesian coordinates _(x,y)_ but not for Earth reference systems. The latutude tradtitonally comes first (e.g. _(latitude,longitude)_), and since North is traditionally "up" on a map, that reverses the interpretation of the coordinates to _(vertical,horizontal)_. This is definitely a better fit for [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which wiki you're referring to, but it's wrong.

Latitude is vertical (from south to north), Longitude is horizontal (from west to east)

So `Latitude, Longitude` is like `Y,X`

**Latitude** ranges vertically from -90 (south pole) to +90 (north pole). `0` is the (*horizontal*) equator that separates the southern and northern hemisphere.

**Longitude** ranges horizontally from -180 to 180, where `0` is a *vertical line* that goes through London. Longitude -180 and 180 both represent the same vertical line.

Comment: http://www.learner.org/jnorth/tm/LongitudeIntro.html thanks but in this article, longtitude is vertical (may be I don't know what is the right way of Earth)

Comment: @BằngRikimaru That link is broken (gave me a 404).